# Xilinx Microblaze generation fails on Linux Mint 17.3

Tags: linux, fpga, microblaze

I'm working with Xilinx ISE 14.7 and I would like to embed the Microblaze IP core into my FPGA, but I can't get the IP core generator working on Linux.

I got it working on Windows 7: everything worked fine, including simulation! I then installed Linux Mint 17.3 on my PC, installed the Xilinx ISE, set everything up, but I get a strange Tcl error message when I generate the Microblaze IP. The generation of a FiFo IP has no problem; the generator only fails on Microblaze. My PC CPU is a 64-bit Intel dual-core.

The console output is the following:

```
INFO:sim:172 - Generating IP...
Applying current project options...
Finished applying current project options.
WARNING:sim - Verilog simulation file type 'Behavioral' is not valid for this
   core. Overriding with simulation file type 'Structural'.
WARNING:sim - A core named 'microblaze_mcs' already exists in the project.
   Output products for this core may be overwritten.
Resolving generics for 'microblaze_mcs'...
WARNING:sim - Verilog simulation file type 'Behavioral' is not valid for this
   core. Overriding with simulation file type 'Structural'.
WARNING:sim - A core named 'microblaze_mcs' already exists in the project.
   Output products for this core may be overwritten.
Applying external generics to 'microblaze_mcs'...
Delivering associated files for 'microblaze_mcs'...
Generating implementation netlist for 'microblaze_mcs'...
INFO:sim - Pre-processing HDL files for 'microblaze_mcs'...
Running synthesis for 'microblaze_mcs'
Running ngcbuild...
INFO:sim - Running microblaze_mcs_gen_script.tcl
WARNING:coreutil - no files matched glob pattern "./_cg/*/system_template.tcl"
   while executing "glob "./_cg/*/system_template.tcl""
   (procedure "bmm_xml" line 244)
   invoked from within
   "bmm_xml $argc $argv"
   invoked from within
   "return [bmm_xml $argc $argv]"
   (file "/opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/coregen/ip/xilinx/primary/com/xilinx/ip/microblaze_mcs_v1_4/microblaze_mcs_gen_script.tcl" line 482)ERROR:sim - Unable to evaluate Tcl file:
   /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/coregen/ip/xilinx/primary/com/xilinx/ip/microblaze_mcs_v1_4/microblaze_mcs_gen_script.tcl
ERROR:sim - Failed executing Tcl generator.
ERROR:sim - Failed to generate 'microblaze_mcs'.  Failed executing Tcl
   generator.

Wrote CGP file for project 'microblaze_mcs'.
Core Generator edit command failed.
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: If you haven't had any responses after 3 hrs, I would recommend looking for a microblaze forum or other specialist site. And, you might get a slightly different viewership if you use `flag` link and ask for a moderator to move it to the related site http://unix.stackexchange.com. Good luck!